# BuddyPress - Message's Send To auto-fill functionality not working

Tags: buddypress

The "Compose" page has a field labeled "Send To" that seems to attempt a call to get names, but nothing happens. I checked for JavaScript errors and there were none. I have "Friend Connections" disabled, but I also tried with it enabled and the profiles being friends. I don't know how to further troubleshoot the issue.

Comment: Your question should be specific to WordPress. Generic PHP/JS/SQL/HTML/CSS questions might be better asked at Stack Overflow or another appropriate Stack Exchange network site. Third party plugins and themes are off topic, they are better asked about at their developers' support routes.

Comment: Have you checked the PHP error logs? You could test to see if it's a conflict with your theme or another plugin. Switch to a default WordPress theme and try disabling all plugins to see if it fixes.

Comment: @Mat You've stated "Third party plugins and themes are off topic, they are better asked about at their developers' support routes.", but I've found those other support platforms to be less responsive than SO. I thought some people here might overlap in knowledge of a common plugin. Should I restrict myself from these 3rd party posts or is your comment suggesting not to expect an answer?

Comment: I was just stating the WP Stack Exchange guidelines and that you shouldn't expect to get an answer here. Have you logged a support query with the plugin developers and have you read and tried what I said in my second comment?

Comment: I did test for theme/plugin conflicts by disabling all plugins except BuddyPress and activating WP default theme. Also checked for PHP and JS errors, but found none. There has to be something I'm missing, but I understand it'll be hard to pin-point the issue unless someone went through a similar situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The auto-fill functionality does not seem to work if Friend Connections is disabled. I found a plugin that has an option to make auto-fill work for all members.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/buddyextender/